# How do I setup redirection for https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2

I have domain like, example.com where I want `https://example.com` to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/`

Does anyone have any recommendation on how to set this up?

I tried setting up a apache virtual host for example.com on the same server and added a redirection rule. But, `https://example.com` does not redirect. Instead, files get served for the request.

I also get the error `_default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence` when starting apache.

Comment: Just to check the obvious.  Are you certain that your certificate is valid for both names?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examples.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put that in a `.htaccess` in the root of the Document_Root for that domain

Comment: I don't get it. This seems to say "if we are on http (NOT https) and the host is not www.example.com, then change the URL to http://examples.com". That is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Just make sure you have a LoadModule for mod-rewrite in there before this lot.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use Apache rewrite engine to do that, it exists a simpler and more efficient solution: use the 'redirect' directive.

On the virtual host serving https://example.com, put the following line: 
Redirect / https://www.example.com